# import images with product

Tags: magento-1.7, image, importexport, avs-fastsimpleimport

It seems like I am the only one who cannot make use of `addImageToGallery()`, as I found many solutions of importing images to/with a product through this function.

First of all, I cannot use directly `$product->addImageToGallery()` as I found in all the examples, because I get error to call it on a non-object. Maybe because my `$product` is a `SimpleXMLElement` object. Therefore I went to this solution:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->$model->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
```

I don't know if that is correct and if it is working, because my overall solution is not working. That was first.

Second, for a new product, the image gallery is null, so it has to be set. As I found in many examples, people use `$product->setMediaGallery()`. That's cool and easy. Too bad that there is NO such function in the API. What is going on around here?!

Third, I am lost and have no idea how to proceed. I also tried the old goodie way: [here go down to the end of Page 3, where he talks about Product Image.](http://www.integer-net.de/download/ImportExport_EN.pdf)

That is my overall code, that I have, and that doesn't work:

```
    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product->$model->setMediaGallery(array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
    $filePath = $importImagesDirectory.$this->_getPresentationAttributeValue($product, '@Art="Bild" and @Rang="1"'); //this gives me full path of the image. It's correct, no worries.
    $product->$model->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
```

Comment: Why this: $product->$model, I can't figure out what is this?

Comment: @mageUz - because I cannot make directly `$product->Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->addImageToMediaGallery()`. And also `$product->addImageToMediaGallery()` does not work.

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code, so we know what $product is

Answer (score 2):

No offense, but do you understand what

```
$product->$model->setMediaGallery()
```

and

```
$product->Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->addImageToMediaGallery()
```

means?

I would say `$product->Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->addImageToMediaGallery()` should produce a parser error, I have no clue what PHP would do with this.

This `$product->$model->setMediaGallery()` means you are trying to access a public property of `$product` with the name `$model` (which should be a string!), so no luck here too.

So what you want is simply `$model->addImageToMediaGallery()`